# How to create a jasper table and textfields inside the list component with XML datasource?

Tags: jasper-reports, xmldatasource

I am trying to generate report using Jasper iReport Designer 5.6.0, where there is a list with table and some textfields. The generated report should look like this:

[image]

To do this, I'm using the following XML file as datasource:

```
<report>
    <subreport>
        <nameOfState>USA</nameOfState>
        <persons>
            <person>
                <dateOfBirth>1989-02-01T00:00:00.000Z</dateOfBirth>
                <fullName>Skyler White</fullName>
                <address>Albuquerque 87107</address>
            </person>
            <person>
                <dateOfBirth>1962-02-01T00:00:00.000Z</dateOfBirth>
                <fullName>Jesse Pinkman</fullName>
                <address>Santa Fé 28</address>
                <companies>
                    <company>
                        <nameOfCompany>Company 124</nameOfCompany>
                        <addressOfCompany>Santa Fé 158</addressOfCompany>
                    </company>
                </companies>
            </person>
        </persons>
    </subreport>
    <subreport>
        <nameOfState>Germany</nameOfState>
            <person>
                <dateOfBirth>1970-02-01T00:00:00.000Z</dateOfBirth>
                <fullName>Hank Schrader</fullName>
                <address>El Paso 17</address>
                <companies>
                    <company>
                        <nameOfCompany>El Paso Company</nameOfCompany>
                        <addressOfCompany>El Paso 28</addressOfCompany>
                    </company>
                    <company>
                        <nameOfCompany>COMPANY EPC</nameOfCompany>
                        <addressOfCompany>Santa Fé 18</addressOfCompany>
                    </company>
                </companies>
            </person>
        </persons>
    </subreport>
</report>
```

And jrxml template:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1_subreport1" pageWidth="756" pageHeight="140" whenNoDataType="BlankPage" columnWidth="756" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" whenResourceMissingType="Error" isIgnorePagination="true" uuid="0a5fd60a-c7ea-46b7-a1e6-484cdedee54a">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.7715610000000022"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <style name="table 3">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 3_TH" mode="Opaque">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 3_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFD0BF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 3_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="PersonsDataset" uuid="cf4c2515-8d53-4c2a-a6ca-d33257aa8e74">
        <queryString language="xPath">
            <![CDATA[/subreport/persons/person]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="dateOfBirth" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[dateOfBirth]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="fullName" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[fullName]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="address" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[address]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="CompanyDataset" uuid="80440d3f-8de3-4fe7-8d02-62734435d23d">
        <queryString language="xPath">
            <![CDATA[/company]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="nameOfCompany" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[child::text()]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="addressOfCompany" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[child::text()]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/subreport/persons/person]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="nameOfState" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[nameOfState]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="140" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="36" width="753" height="104" uuid="e417d0a1-9945-42e9-b12b-8bf0573c93ba"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="PersonsDataset" uuid="c0d23173-9df2-452c-9d97-78dee6f766ef">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("/subreport/persons/person")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="104" width="753">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="11" y="11" width="100" height="13" backcolor="#C0C0C0" uuid="21b820ed-d7eb-4c92-a1c7-8b60880bb3b6"/>
                            <box leftPadding="2">
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font size="8" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[Full name]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="11" y="24" width="100" height="13" backcolor="#C0C0C0" uuid="1b637cc8-c654-4734-9ee8-debc404931a2"/>
                            <box leftPadding="2">
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font size="8" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[Address:]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="11" y="37" width="100" height="13" backcolor="#C0C0C0" uuid="08dc2de1-652a-4cd5-b572-344dbadb3b91"/>
                            <box leftPadding="2">
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font size="8" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[Date of birth:]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="112" y="11" width="239" height="13" uuid="d18bd33c-028a-4cae-8748-e0f5b12faff5"/>
                            <box leftPadding="2">
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font size="8" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fullName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="112" y="24" width="239" height="13" uuid="242e9491-3e9b-450c-bbb8-bf7565e67fa6"/>
                            <box leftPadding="2">
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font size="8" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{address}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="112" y="37" width="239" height="13" uuid="efe7b9b3-7573-411a-bada-620939ada8dc"/>
                            <box leftPadding="2">
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font size="8" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dateOfBirth}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <componentElement>
                            <reportElement key="NajdenaOsobaTable1" style="table 3" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Transparent" x="96" y="66" width="645" height="25" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="99480409-009b-4f75-b435-ad99403ddb56"/>
                            <jr:table whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
                                <datasetRun subDataset="CompanyDataset" uuid="cc9ac018-67f1-4011-995c-d95cd30b8ce3">
                                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("/subreport/person/companies/company")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                                </datasetRun>
                                <jr:column width="125" uuid="db854a2c-d49e-46ae-a57b-38be7cd8e7f8">
                                    <jr:tableHeader style="table 3_TH" height="17" rowSpan="1">
                                        <staticText>
                                            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="125" height="17" backcolor="#C0C0C0" uuid="8ef76d08-af87-4e3b-9436-2f9863275e50"/>
                                            <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                                                <pen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                            </box>
                                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                                <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                                            </textElement>
                                            <text><![CDATA[Name of Company]]></text>
                                        </staticText>
                                    </jr:tableHeader>
                                    <jr:detailCell style="table 3_TD" height="16" rowSpan="1">
                                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="125" height="16" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="d1bcdf70-4494-4552-9c84-2c1acf29d5fa"/>
                                            <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                                                <pen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                            </box>
                                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                                <font fontName="Arial" size="8" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                                            </textElement>
                                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nameOfCompany}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                        </textField>
                                    </jr:detailCell>
                                </jr:column>
                                <jr:column width="160" uuid="db2c69c2-67ce-4de0-b8fc-4f24b969127f">
                                    <jr:tableHeader style="table 3_TH" height="17" rowSpan="1">
                                        <staticText>
                                            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="160" height="17" backcolor="#C0C0C0" uuid="80f738f8-58c1-4959-b441-b1a3424e6bd6"/>
                                            <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                                                <pen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                            </box>
                                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                                <font fontName="Arial" size="8" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                                            </textElement>
                                            <text><![CDATA[Address of Company]]></text>
                                        </staticText>
                                    </jr:tableHeader>
                                    <jr:detailCell style="table 3_TD" height="16" rowSpan="1">
                                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="160" height="16" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="6351ecdf-eb49-4738-bb51-dee451c5761b"/>
                                            <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                                                <pen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                            </box>
                                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                                <font fontName="Arial" size="8" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                                            </textElement>
                                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{addressOfCompany}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                        </textField>
                                    </jr:detailCell>
                                </jr:column>
                            </jr:table>
                        </componentElement>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="12" y="10" width="100" height="20" uuid="a8753122-9817-4500-81f2-99d703df00b8"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nameOfState}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

And this is what I'm getting as resulting report (grey line is a pagebreak):

[image]

This is image what the report inspector looks like in my iReport Designer

[image]

So I am only using the detail band in this subreport.

**EDIT:** 
List is necesarry because the data are from multiple countries, and this jrxml represent subreport which is nested in the main report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all about defining your subDataset (with related fields) and XPath query in subDataSource correctly. A general indication would be query down to node, then generate subDatasource stepping back one node.

The solution in this case is to first query for the detail band (main XPath query of report)

```
<queryString language="XPath">
    <![CDATA[/report/subreport]]>
</queryString>
```

This way in detail band you access you first fields `nameOfState`.

***Then***

In detail band while we are "running" on node `subreport` we add the `jr:list` component the `subDataSource` will be `/subreport/persons/person` to access the fields dateOfBirth, fullName etc.

```
<datasetRun subDataset="PersonsDataset" uuid="c0d23173-9df2-452c-9d97-78dee6f766ef">
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("/subreport/persons/person")]]></dataSourceExpression>
</datasetRun>
```

**and then** we are at the node person so for the `jr:table` your query is `/person/companies/company`

```
<datasetRun subDataset="CompanyDataset" uuid="cc9ac018-67f1-4011-995c-d95cd30b8ce3">
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("/person/companies/company")]]></dataSourceExpression>
</datasetRun>
```

For subDataset and field definition see the full example, it's more straight forward, since you are creating the datasource (subDatasource) the XPath query is actually not need for the subDataset (it's only needed on main query), you only need to have correct field declaration with same names as xml tags.

### Full jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1_subreport1" pageWidth="756" pageHeight="140" whenNoDataType="BlankPage" columnWidth="756" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" whenResourceMissingType="Error" isIgnorePagination="true" uuid="0a5fd60a-c7ea-46b7-a1e6-484cdedee54a">
    <style name="table 3">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 3_TH" mode="Opaque">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 3_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFD0BF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 3_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="PersonsDataset" uuid="cf4c2515-8d53-4c2a-a6ca-d33257aa8e74">
        <field name="dateOfBirth" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[dateOfBirth]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="fullName" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[fullName]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="address" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[address]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="CompanyDataset" uuid="80440d3f-8de3-4fe7-8d02-62734435d23d">
        <field name="nameOfCompany" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[nameOfCompany]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="addressOfCompany" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[addressOfCompany]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/report/subreport]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="nameOfState" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression" value="nameOfState"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[nameOfState]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="140" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="36" width="753" height="104" uuid="e417d0a1-9945-42e9-b12b-8bf0573c93ba"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="PersonsDataset" uuid="c0d23173-9df2-452c-9d97-78dee6f766ef">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("/subreport/persons/person")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="104" width="753">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="11" y="11" width="100" height="13" backcolor="#C0C0C0" uuid="21b820ed-d7eb-4c92-a1c7-8b60880bb3b6"/>
                            <box leftPadding="2">
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font size="8" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[Full name]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="11" y="24" width="100" height="13" backcolor="#C0C0C0" uuid="1b637cc8-c654-4734-9ee8-debc404931a2"/>
                            <box leftPadding="2">
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font size="8" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[Address:]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="11" y="37" width="100" height="13" backcolor="#C0C0C0" uuid="08dc2de1-652a-4cd5-b572-344dbadb3b91"/>
                            <box leftPadding="2">
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font size="8" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[Date of birth:]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="112" y="11" width="239" height="13" uuid="d18bd33c-028a-4cae-8748-e0f5b12faff5"/>
                            <box leftPadding="2">
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font size="8" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fullName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="112" y="24" width="239" height="13" uuid="242e9491-3e9b-450c-bbb8-bf7565e67fa6"/>
                            <box leftPadding="2">
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font size="8" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{address}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="112" y="37" width="239" height="13" uuid="efe7b9b3-7573-411a-bada-620939ada8dc"/>
                            <box leftPadding="2">
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font size="8" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dateOfBirth}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <componentElement>
                            <reportElement key="NajdenaOsobaTable1" style="table 3" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Transparent" x="96" y="66" width="645" height="25" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="99480409-009b-4f75-b435-ad99403ddb56"/>
                            <jr:table whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
                                <datasetRun subDataset="CompanyDataset" uuid="cc9ac018-67f1-4011-995c-d95cd30b8ce3">
                                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("/person/companies/company")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                                </datasetRun>
                                <jr:column width="125" uuid="db854a2c-d49e-46ae-a57b-38be7cd8e7f8">
                                    <jr:tableHeader style="table 3_TH" height="17" rowSpan="1">
                                        <staticText>
                                            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="125" height="17" backcolor="#C0C0C0" uuid="8ef76d08-af87-4e3b-9436-2f9863275e50"/>
                                            <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                                                <pen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                            </box>
                                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                                <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                                            </textElement>
                                            <text><![CDATA[Name of Company]]></text>
                                        </staticText>
                                    </jr:tableHeader>
                                    <jr:detailCell style="table 3_TD" height="16" rowSpan="1">
                                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="125" height="16" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="d1bcdf70-4494-4552-9c84-2c1acf29d5fa"/>
                                            <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                                                <pen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                            </box>
                                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                                <font fontName="Arial" size="8" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                                            </textElement>
                                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nameOfCompany}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                        </textField>
                                    </jr:detailCell>
                                </jr:column>
                                <jr:column width="160" uuid="db2c69c2-67ce-4de0-b8fc-4f24b969127f">
                                    <jr:tableHeader style="table 3_TH" height="17" rowSpan="1">
                                        <staticText>
                                            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="160" height="17" backcolor="#C0C0C0" uuid="80f738f8-58c1-4959-b441-b1a3424e6bd6"/>
                                            <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                                                <pen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                            </box>
                                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                                <font fontName="Arial" size="8" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                                            </textElement>
                                            <text><![CDATA[Address of Company]]></text>
                                        </staticText>
                                    </jr:tableHeader>
                                    <jr:detailCell style="table 3_TD" height="16" rowSpan="1">
                                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="160" height="16" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="6351ecdf-eb49-4738-bb51-dee451c5761b"/>
                                            <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
                                                <pen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                                            </box>
                                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                                <font fontName="Arial" size="8" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                                            </textElement>
                                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{addressOfCompany}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                        </textField>
                                    </jr:detailCell>
                                </jr:column>
                            </jr:table>
                        </componentElement>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="12" y="10" width="100" height="20" uuid="a8753122-9817-4500-81f2-99d703df00b8"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nameOfState}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

### Result

[image: output]